# Android pictures, filters and memory issues

Tags: android, camera, image

Due to the fragmentation in camera equipment taking pictures seems to be not unproblematic.

Especially taking pictures in full quality often times lead to memory problems. I don't own a device with a 8MP Camera, so I can't reliably test. Is there a bulletproof way of taking pictures in Android?

I also wrote a filter (sepia) that works well with smaller images. For full size images there are again some memory issues. For this I'm creating an new bitmap with the same dimensions as the bitmap that needs to be filtered.

```
Bitmap filteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

It's clear that the app-memory isn't sufficient for two full size bitmaps. Is there another way I could create such a filter?

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` gives you a 32 bit bitmap.  If your taking pictures with the camera I don't see why you would need the alpha channel for those images.  So you could use `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` instead and that should considerably reduce the size of your bitmaps.